# It is possible to write to Mariadb using plain MySql jdbc Driver. Then why use separate MaraDB driver?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What difference does it make, if we use plain MySQL JDBC driver to write to MariaDB. It still works. Why use a separate driver?. Does it do any harm to MariaDB cluster if we use MySQL Driver?

Comment: can you garantee it will work tomorrow? can you garantee that MySQL and MariaDB archtecture wont diverge in the future breaking the connections made with MySQL Driver and crashing programs using it? Chosing one driver to use is pretty simple task for dependency management, it makes no sense to "push" something explicitily wrong just because your tested didn't crash

Comment: I think that for most uses, MariaDB and MySQL are interchangeable. There are minor differences in capabilities, but the main difference being is in licensing.

Comment: I think that for most uses, MariaDB and MySQL are interchangeable. There are minor differences in capabilities, but the main difference being is in licensing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MariaDB and MySQL JDBC implementations are mostly interchangeable. The main differences are in the features and performance of the drivers. For example, the MariaDB JDBC connector supports failover with AWS Aurora: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/#failover-parameters